# Why are some of my div elements been cut off horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I've found some (what I think) is rather strange behaviour. Take this code:

```
<body style="background-color:#1b1b1b">
  <div style="width:100%;height:1px;background-color:#f00" /><br />
  <div style="width:1300px;height:300px;background-color:#fff;margin: 0 auto;" />
</body>
```

I haven't been doing web development for long, but I would've thought that that first `div` would always be the entire width of the page, no matter how much re-sizing I do to the browser window. However, when I re-size the width of the browser window so it's less than the width of the lower `div` (`1300px`) and scroll across, the upper `div` that's supposed to be `width:100%` seems to be cut off. I've recorded this behaviour:

[http://i.imgur.com/5bFIj0O.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/5bFIj0O.gifv)
(sorry about it not been embedded, seems the `gifv` file format is not supported here.)

Any suggestions to this problem (it's probably a lot simpler that I think)?

Comment: the div with `width: 100%` is going to be 100% of the containing element, which is `body`. By default, the width of `body` will match that of the viewport. So `body` is only as wide as your viewport, then the div with `width: 100%` will be that same width, and the inner div with `width: 1300px` is overflowing outside of both of those. That's why the red line cuts off at the width of the viewport. If you added `overflow: hidden` to either `body` or the div with `width: 100%` you wouldn't see the overflow from the 1300px wide div.

Comment: What if I needed to horizontal scroll? Say there was content in the lower `div`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If the upper div is supposed to be just a line, you can add a border-top attribute to the parent (in your example <body>) element instead.

Comment: This was just a bit of code I wrote to show my problem. I'm actually developing a larger site where putting a `border-top` on `body` would not work.

Comment: @carefulnow http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrpjbv

Comment: Thanks @MichaelCoker, I'll probably use this one (you might want to put it as an answer so I can accept it). However, is there really *no way* to have a simple `div` that sticks to 100% of the page width?

Comment: @carefulnow the simplest way is probably to assign the width as `min-width` to the outer div http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/xqprdB

Comment: @carefulnow: You an accepted a (bad) edit, then you accepted a rollback of that edit. Please don't just arbitrarily accept all edits. Think about them before acting. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, I noticed that. Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. I was actually suprised such a high rep user would submit such a bad edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div with width: 100% is going to be 100% of the containing element, which is body. By default, the width of body will match that of the viewport. So body is only as wide as your viewport, then the div with width: 100% will be that same width, and the inner div with width: 1300px is overflowing outside of both of those. That's why the red line cuts off at the width of the viewport. If you added overflow: hidden to either body or the div with width: 100% you wouldn't see the overflow from the 1300px wide div.

If you want a horizontal scroll, you can add `overflow-x: scroll;` to the div with `width: 100%;`

```html
<body style="background-color:#1b1b1b">
  <div style="width:100%;border-top: 1px solid #f00;padding-top: 1em; overflow-x: scroll;">
    <div style="width:1300px;height:300px;background-color:#fff;margin:auto;">foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo </div>
  </div>
</body>
```